# Open powerpoint from memory

Tags: c#, interop, powerpoint

Is it possible to open a powerpoint presentation from a file purely in memory?

Let's say I'd download a presentation from a server, do I have to save this file locally to analyse it with interop?

Comment: what's the problem with using a temporary file in the TEMP dir?

Comment: That's the alternative, however it would be nice if we could skip that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other posters suggested there is no straight-forward way. You could try loading the file using IStorage/IPersistStorage which may or may not work. See some instructions for Excel [here](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/excel-ipersiststorage-load-fails-help-24976002.html). However, using a temp file will be *much* easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [RAM disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_disk_software). That way the presentation file is actually in memory, but appears to be on disk as far as PowerPoint is concerned.

Comment: I doubt I can achieve this using just interop and C# :p

Comment: Depends whether you have control of the environment your tool is running on. For client software, you're probably right. For software running on your own PC or server, you can install a third-party RAM disk and it will just appear to be another disk as far as the OS is concerned.

Comment: I have no control over the environment. It's not that much effort to save the file, I was just wondering whether it was possible to read it from memory. I didn't find it anywhere so far...